# Can I get $PS1 or similar dynamic title in the title line of Putty?

Tags: putty

At work I typically log in to one particular linux host, let's call it the jumphost, using Putty from my Windows workstation, then access other servers (we have more than a thousand) from that using ssh.

The title line in Putty by default shows the user@host, and I often end up with a dozen Putty windows to various servers, but all has the same title so it becomes hard to find back to the right one, especially from the task line at the bottom of the desktop.

I see it is possible to set the title dynamically e.g. by adding the following to ~/.bashrc:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;${USER}@$(hostname)\007"'
```

but this doesn't help me since I often log in to new servers.

Are there any other solutions? Something I can configure in Putty, or something I can do on the jumphost?